# Shipping Method list by group at checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

Can anyone help me to show shipping methods by group as it showing at cart page.

**Cart Page:**

[image]

**Checkout Page:**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

overirde the the below file in theme or custom module

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
>
> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

In shipping.html
Replace the comment code with below code

```
<!-- <render args="shippingMethodListTemplate"/> -->
<fieldset class="fieldset rate" data-bind="visible: (rates().length > 0)">
    <dl class="items methods" data-bind="foreach: shippingRateGroups">
        <dt class="item-title"><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></dt>
        <dd class="item-options" data-bind="foreach: { data:$parent.getRatesForGroup($data), as: 'method' }">
            <div click="element.selectShippingMethod" data-bind="css: {'field choice item': available, 'message error': !available} ">
                <!-- ko ifnot: (available) -->
                <div data-bind="text: error_message"></div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: (available) -->
                <input type="radio"
                       class="radio"
                       data-bind="
                            click: $parents[1].selectShippingMethod,
                            checked: element.isSelected,
                            attr: {
                                    value: carrier_code + '_' + method_code,
                                    id: 's_method_' + carrier_code + '_' + method_code
                                    }
                            "/>
                <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {for: 's_method_' + carrier_code + '_' + method_code}">
                    <!-- ko text: $data.method_title --><!-- /ko -->
                    <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" />
                </label>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</fieldset>
```

In shipping.js
add the below code arroud line number 232 in shipping method view code section

```
shippingRateGroups: ko.observableArray([]),
initObservable: function () {
    var self = this;

    this._super();

    this.rates.subscribe(function (rates) {
        self.shippingRateGroups([]);
        _.each(rates, function (rate) {
            var carrierTitle = rate['carrier_title'];

            if (self.shippingRateGroups.indexOf(carrierTitle) === -1) {
                self.shippingRateGroups.push(carrierTitle);
            }
        });
    });

    return this;
},

getRatesForGroup: function (shippingRateGroupTitle) {
    return _.filter(this.rates(), function (rate) {
        return shippingRateGroupTitle === rate['carrier_title'];
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would need to override the shipping method list *templates*. Copy `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` and `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js` to your custom module, then edit around these lines:

```
<!--Shipping method template-->
<li id="opc-shipping_method"
    class="checkout-shipping-method"
    data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
    role="presentation">
    <div class="checkout-shipping-method">
        <div class="step-title"
             translate="'Shipping Methods'"
             data-role="title" />

        <each args="getRegion('before-shipping-method-form')" render="" />

        <div id="checkout-step-shipping_method"
             class="step-content"
             data-role="content"
             role="tabpanel"
             aria-hidden="false">
            <form id="co-shipping-method-form"
                  class="form methods-shipping"
                  if="rates().length"
                  submit="setShippingInformation"
                  novalidate="novalidate">

                <render args="shippingMethodListTemplate"/>
```

note the last line above. You can override it with your desired HTML or edit partial templates that's defined in `shipping.js` around these lines:

```
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping',
        shippingFormTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form',
        shippingMethodListTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-list',
        shippingMethodItemTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-item'
    },
```

so, you can override `shipping.js` with your custom module by defining it in `requirejs-config.js` and rename it for instance to `shipping-override.js` like:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': 
                'YourNamespace_Module/js/view/shipping-override'
        }
    }
};
```

don't forget to edit your `shipping-override.js` in this line:

```
shippingMethodListTemplate: 'YourNamespace_Module/shipping-address/shipping-method-list',
shippingMethodItemTemplate: 'YourNamespace_Module/shipping-address/shipping-method-item'
```

and the partial templates `shipping-method-list.html` or `shipping-method-item.html` are in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/` directory. Copy them too to your custom module.

FYI, in this case, I use Magento 2.2.x

Edit: for reference here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_shipping_methods.html